# Dynamic Table: INDIRECT and INDEX to compare cell content in array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas, excel-indirect

**Overview**:I am trying to use INDIRECT combined with INDEX, ROW and COLUMN to get a dynamic table working.

**Problem**:

1. For each cell of a given column in Worksheet1, read the content of the cell to its left.
2. Compare the content of a column from Worksheet2 to the read one .
3. For each match, get the value of a variable from Worksheet2 .
4. Evaluate the max of the found values, copy it into Worksheet1 original cell.

**How I'm doing it (Wrong, apparently)**:

```
{=MAX(IF('Worksheet 2'!$A$4:$A$101=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1;4)); 'Worksheet 2'!$D$4:$D$101))}
```

**What I would expect it to do:**

1. `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1;4))` --- Read content to the cell on the left in Worksheet 1
2. `'Worksheet 2'!$A$4:$A$101=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1;4))` --- Get an array of TRUE/FALSE values, where TRUE is found where Worksheet 2 column A contains the value previousl
3. `IF('Worksheet 2'!$A$4:$A$101=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1;4)); 'Worksheet 2'!$D$4:$D$101)` --- For each TRUE, extract the corresponding value from COLUMN D of Worksheet 2
4. `{=MAX(IF('Worksheet 2'!$A$4:$A$101=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1;4)); 'Worksheet 2'!$D$4:$D$101))}` --- From the COLUMN D extracted values, take the MAX

**What I get**: A #VALUE! Error.

Can somebody explain me why and propose a feasible substitution?

Comment: The way your formula is written, it looks like `INDIRECT` has a second argument which is `'Worksheet 2'!$D$4:$D$101`. Was this a mistake? You might be missing a closing parenthesis in your formula.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 -  The bracket got lost in translation, I just corrected it - Unfortunately that was not the problem but thanks for lettimg me notice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `INDIRECT` cell reference is part of an array formula, so you get `{"A1"}` instead of `"A1"`, for example.

This can be resolved by using `MAX`, e.g.:

```
{=MAX(IF('Worksheet 2'!$A$4:$A$101=MAX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-1;4))); 'Worksheet 2'!$D$4:$D$101))}
```

(It looks like you also had a few brackets out of place.)

Update:

This is a better version which will work for your text columns (use `MAX` on the `ROW` and `COLUMN` functions):

```
=MAX(IF('Worksheet 2'!$A$4:$A$101=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MAX(ROW());MAX(COLUMN())-1;4)); 'Worksheet 2'!$D$4:$D$101))
```

Comment: My INDIRECT pointed cell will contain text and not number. Is there a workaround for this? Using MAX is giving me always 0 as return value.

Comment: I got it working with INDEX to access the value! Thanks, that worked like a charm and got me insights on how array formulas behave (:

Comment: Cool! I've updated my answer with a better version anyway.